# Makefile: ignore file in automatically generated dependencies

Tags: makefile, stm32, stm32cubemx

I have the following makefile, (mostly) generated by STM32CubeMX and slightly modified:

```
##########################################################################################################################
# File automatically-generated by tool: [projectgenerator] version: [3.16.0] date: [Mon Jun 06 11:00:27 SGT 2022]
##########################################################################################################################

# ------------------------------------------------
# Generic Makefile (based on gcc)
#
# ChangeLog :
#   2017-02-10 - Several enhancements + project update mode
#   2015-07-22 - first version
# ------------------------------------------------

######################################
# target
######################################
TARGET := mytarget

######################################
# building variables
######################################
# debug build?
DEBUG := 1
# optimization
OPT := -Og

#######################################
# paths
#######################################
# Build path
BUILD_DIR := build

######################################
# source
######################################
# Generated directories
CORE_SOURCES := $(filter-out Core/Src/main.c,$(wildcard Core/**/*.c))
DRIVER_SOURCES := $(wildcard Drivers/STM32WBxx_HAL_Driver/**/*.c)
C_SOURCES := $(CORE_SOURCES) $(DRIVER_SOURCES)

# ASM sources
ASM_SOURCES := startup_stm32wb55xx_cm4.s

# C++ sources
CXX_SOURCES := $(wildcard App/**/*.cpp App/*.cpp)

#######################################
# binaries
#######################################
PREFIX := arm-none-eabi-
# The gcc compiler bin path can be either defined in make command via GCC_PATH variable (> make GCC_PATH=xxx)
# either it can be added to the PATH environment variable.
ifdef GCC_PATH
CC  := $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc
CXX := $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)g++
AS  := $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP  := $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ  := $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)size
else
CC  := $(PREFIX)gcc
CXX := $(PREFIX)g++
AS  := $(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP  := $(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ  := $(PREFIX)size
endif
HEX := $(CP) -O ihex
BIN := $(CP) -O binary -S
 
#######################################
# CFLAGS
#######################################
# cpu
CPU := -mcpu=cortex-m4

# fpu
FPU := -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16

# float-abi
FLOAT-ABI := -mfloat-abi=hard

# mcu
MCU := $(CPU) -mthumb $(FPU) $(FLOAT-ABI)

# macros for gcc
# AS defines
AS_DEFS :=

# C defines
C_DEFS :=  \
-DUSE_HAL_DRIVER \
-DSTM32WB55xx


# AS includes
AS_INCLUDES :=

# C includes
C_INCLUDES :=  \
-isystem Core/Inc \
-isystem Drivers/STM32WBxx_HAL_Driver/Inc \
-isystem Drivers/STM32WBxx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy \
-isystem Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32WBxx/Include \
-isystem Drivers/CMSIS/Include


# compile gcc flags
ASFLAGS := $(MCU) $(AS_DEFS) $(AS_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

CFLAGS += $(MCU) $(C_DEFS) $(C_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections
CXXFLAGS += $(MCU) $(C_DEFS) $(C_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -std=c++2a -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror
MAKEFLAGS += --jobs=12

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
CFLAGS += -g -gdwarf-2
CXXFLAGS += -g -gdwarf-2
endif

# Generate dependency information
CFLAGS += -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)"
CXXFLAGS += -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)"

#######################################
# LDFLAGS
#######################################
# link script
LDSCRIPT := stm32wb55xx_flash_cm4.ld

# libraries
LIBS := -lc -lm -lnosys
LIBDIR :=
LDFLAGS := $(MCU) -specs=nano.specs -T$(LDSCRIPT) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) -Wl,-Map=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections

# default action: build all
all: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).hex $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).bin

info: $(info $(VPATH))

#######################################
# build the application
#######################################
# list of C objects
OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o)))
vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(C_SOURCES)))
# list of C++ objects
OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(CXX_SOURCES:.cpp=.o)))
vpath %.cpp $(sort $(dir $(CXX_SOURCES)))
# list of ASM program objects
OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(ASM_SOURCES:.s=.o)))
vpath %.s $(sort $(dir $(ASM_SOURCES)))

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.cpp=.lst)) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.s Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(AS) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS) Makefile
    $(CXX) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@
    $(SZ) $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.hex: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(HEX) $< $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.bin: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(BIN) $< $@    
    
$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir $@        

#######################################
# clean up
#######################################
clean:
    -rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)
  
#######################################
# dependencies
#######################################
-include $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/*.d)

# *** EOF ***
```

Now, the `C_SOURCES` directory (`Core/Src/`, etc) contains `main.c` that I want to ignore (which I have tried to do, with `filter-out`). I have reimplemented all of it in `main.cpp` in `CXX_SOURCES`, i.e. `App/Src/`, which I want to compile instead.

However, it looks like the automatic dependency generation still finds, compiles and links `Core/Src/main.c` instead of `App/Src/main.cpp`. I am very new to makefiles as a whole and am not sure how to handle this. What can I do?

Comment: Could be suffix rules... Try clear suffixes by declaring .SUFFIXES to empty, or run make completely without built-ins using options -r.

Comment: You're going to have to debug this yourself since there's not much we can do to help with this information.  Add `$(info C_SOURCES = $(C_SOURCES))` after you set it to see what it's value is.  Then print the object files you're trying to build, etc.  See where things go wrong.  Just FYI, this syntax: `$(wildcard Core/**/*.c)` doesn't do what you probably think it does: `**` wildcards are advanced features implemented only in shells like bash and zsh (with extensions enabled).  They are not supported by GNU make and mean nothing to it.  That's the same as `$(wildcard Core/*/*.c)`